# Login Active-Directory account require different username values in loginwindow and switch user

Tags: windows, active-directory, mac-osx, authentication, authorization

I've just bind my machine (running Mojave) to new AD server and would like to login to an existing AD account from loginwindow startup screen, but all I get is a tilted password record (indicator that occur once password is incorrect).

Apparently, active-directory account in macOS require different AD account values for username, when trying to switch user using `su` rather that logging-in from loginwindow screen.

when changing the user from terminal command using su, it require the use of `sAMAccountName` attribute as username, and in order to login from loginwindow I was needed to use the full name represented by `dsAttrTypeNative:name` or it wouldn't find the user under the /Search node.

Any idea what the reason is for this difference in the 2 login options?